# C# Generics Class with Interface Implementation Issue (Compiler Errors)

Tags: c#, generics

The generic type uses the interface and the interface uses the type. Is that the cause of this problem? The lines that emit compile errors are marked below. Is there a simple fix?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CcelBookParse.Utility
{
    public interface IListType
    {
        void Initialize(ParseListManager<IListType> value); // Error.
    }

    public class ParseListManager<IListType> : List<IListType> where IListType : new()
    {
        private int NextIndex;

        public ParseListManager() { }

        protected void Initialize()
        {
            NextIndex = 0;
        }

        protected IListType GetNext()
        {
            IListType Result;
            if (Count < NextIndex)
            {
                Result = this[NextIndex];
                Result.Initialize(this); // Error.
            }
            else if (Count == NextIndex)
            {
                Result = new IListType();
                Add(Result);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("List allocation index error.");
            }
            return Result;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: There is no types implementing a `IListType`

Comment: I think you are mixing the generic type `IListType` and the interface `IListType`. Can you please try to use something like `T` as generic type?

Comment: @mu88 I think you are onto something. I'm going to try modifying the class and will post back here with any updates.

Comment: I cannot seem to get the interaction between the interface and the generic type to be what I want, so I'm just going to go for a simpler approach now. I wanted to post the minor updates I made, but comments are limited to a short length, so even this short code won't fit. Thanks everyone for the help! Maybe what I want to do is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare the `ParseListManager`, you are putting a type constraint saying that the type which needs to be used as the generic type needs to have a parameterless constructor (the `new()` after the `where`  keyword).

Also, it's a good idea not to use types which already exist when defining a generic type. Most code I've seen uses something like `TOutput` or a simple `T`.

Regarding the usage, it's a bit weird what you are trying to describe. What's the purpose of the `Initialize` method inside the interface? My interpretation would be something like: each object implementing `IListType` can be initialized with a `ParseListManager`

A solution would be to leave the `Initialize` method in the interface parameterless.

```
public interface IListType
{
    void Initialize();
}

public class ParseListManager<TList> : List<TList> where TList : IListType, new()
{
    private int NextIndex;

    public ParseListManager() { }

    protected void Initialize()
    {
        NextIndex = 0;
    }

    protected TList GetNext()
    {
        TList Result;
        if (Count < NextIndex)
        {
            Result = this[NextIndex];
            Result.Initialize(); 
        }
        else if (Count == NextIndex)
        {
            Result = new TList(); // You cannot instantiate an interface, you need a proper implementation
            Add(Result);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("List allocation index error.");
        }
        return Result;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are correct. I think I mixed up the interface and the generic type a little bit. I am going to try to rework it now and will send an update.

Comment: I cannot seem to get the interaction between the interface and the generic type to be what I want, so I'm just going to go for a simpler approach now. I wanted to post the minor updates I made, but comments are limited to a short length, so even this short code won't fit. Thanks for the help! Maybe what I want to do is not possible.